# Why Object and Array constructor don't need to be prefixed with new for constructing an object?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet :-

```js
function Custom(){}

// prints {}
console.log(Object()); 
// prints []
console.log(Array());
// prints undefined
console.log(Custom())
// prints {}
console.log(new Custom());
```

I know that the Custom function constructor needs a `new` keyword prefixed to bind `this`. Why isn't that necessary for `Array` and `Object` constructors ?

Comment: Because `Custom()` is a function and it doesn't return anything. Unless you [call it with `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) in which case it's the `new` operator that will instantiate and return an object. You can change `Custom()` to return something, then you wouldn't (necessarily) need `new`

Comment: perhaps it's a historical convention - you can make your own `Custom` not require `new` if you really want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [array constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-constructor) says:

> also creates and initializes a new Array object when called as a function rather than as a constructor. Thus the function call Array(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Array(…) with the same arguments.

The [object constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-value) says:

> 1. If NewTarget is neither undefined nor the active function, then
>    a. Return ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%Object.prototype%").
> 2. If value is undefined or null, return ! OrdinaryObjectCreate(%Object.prototype%).
> 3. Return ! ToObject(value).

So it's explicitly noted that `new` isn't required for either of those.

(though, you should probably never be using either `Object` or `Array` as constructors, whether with or without `new` - better to use object and array literals)

It'll be trivial to implement this sort of thing yourself in Custom, if you want - check if the function was called with `new`, and if not, explicitly return something:

```js
function Custom(){
  if (!new.target) {
    return new Custom();
  }
}
console.log(Custom())
console.log(new Custom());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Custom, Object, and Array` all are functions. When you call them, i.e. `Object()`, the value printed is the return value of the function. `Object` and `Array` returns a new empty object and array respectively. While the `Custom` function returns nothing and thus `undefined` is printed.

When you call a function with `new` is creates an object by calling the function as a constructor. As one of the comments mentioned [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) gives more details about the `new` keyword.